# support-material / support-structures Tag unification?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should these two tags be unified? I don't think there is the need to have separate tags for support's structure and material, since the material is in most cases the same as printed. In the few cases it isn't, it would still be fine to have it in a unified support tag, imho.

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree with this request because the two are *technically* different (and I mean technically in literal form).

1. Support material helps define relevance to a specific material type, ie PLA/ABS, PVA, that lime stuff that MakerBot tried selling, wax, etc.
2. Support structures helps define relevance to the existence of support structure being generated and/or their physical dimensions.

So, I guess you could say that *Support Material* is a *what* question <sub>(as-in *what* is it made of)</sub> and *Support Structure* is a *how* and *why* question <sub>(as-in *how* is it made and *why* is it needed)</sub>.

I'd also like to point out that you said

> I don't think there is the need to have separate tags for support's structure and material, since the material is ***in most cases*** the same as printed.

A large factor in maintaining the quality in a site like SE is adhering to all cases, even if that means having a large number of tags to keep track of.

Comment: Ok, I could totally agree with this answer. I didn't think of it in a way that someone would want to clarify that he/she has a problem with support when printing ABS, but not PLA. If these cases are found by users and if we want to keep the diversity for that, I agree to leave them separate tags. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: Not a problem, thank you for raising the question :)