# Tag synonym: support & support-structures

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

We have two tags: [support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) & [support-structures](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-structures)

These two are essentially the same thing. Even the abbreviated tag-wikis are pretty much saying the same thing. IMHO, we should combine the two tags as they are superfluous.

There was the Meta question: [support-material / support-structures Tag unification?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/11242) which was about combining [support-material](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-material) & [support-structures](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-structures) which was turned down, but this request is quite different.

Comment: I think we have to remove the "support" tag (support can have a different meaning), support-structures is more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags [support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) & [support-structures](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-structures) are in fact referring to exactly the same thing!

Furthermore, the meaning of support can be interpreted differently (i.e. helping out).

I support renaming/merging the [support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) labelled questions to [support-structures](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-structures). This implies that the [support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tag is removed and it could be reinstated at any time by new questions. Users with enough reputation can remove the [support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tag if it gets recreated and we could create a synonym later.

In my humble opinion, the best solution may be to rename [support](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) to [supports](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supports) and then make it a synonym for [support-structures](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-structures)!

Comment: Actually, you should have "support" point to "support-structures", if that is your intent? If you just rename one to the other without pointing it, the old tag can be recreated. As a mod, you can create the synonym directly without the voting hassle (it's hard to find five non-mod votes to push the synonym forward as they have to have "so many" points within the tag to vote on the synonym ... it's ridiculous).

Comment: I did not think of it being re-created... We can anyways remove the `support` tag if it gets recreated or create a synonym later. I'm more in favor of renaming `support` to `supports` and then make it a synonym for `support-structures`. (I was thinking of a mod forced change, no voting)

Comment: Yah, "supports" would work as well. I'm just thinking of removing the confusion up front. A little more work now creates a lot less work later, kind of thing. The thing I don't like about "support" as meaning someone coming on here to receive support ... isn't that what they come on here for help with in the first place? It seems like a superfluous kind of tag ... sort of "self fulfilling" or something, I don't know. It's like a tag named "help" ... lol.

Comment: I'm sometimes surprised by the stuff the new users pull, but I'm always patient, and wouldn't be surprised to see the help or support tag appear... So we rename support to supports and create a synonym, the support structure will be the main tag.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a synonym - <strike>apparently it needs [some votes](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/support-structures/synonyms)</strike>.

Comment: There's a problem with "voting" on the synonyms. You have to have enough tag votes in both to make the vote. I thought it made the synonym automagically for mods? Also, I would have thought it should be the other way, with [tag:support] being the main tag?

Comment: (a) Yeah, I was surprised when it didn't just make it and required votes (maybe I am not all powerful after all?) for approval. (b) I thought `support-structures` should be the main as it matches `support-material` in format, and it is a more descriptive name (i.e.,  as `hbp` is the synonym of `heated-bed`) it seems to make more sense to do it that way around... I dunno, it can be swapped if you want.

Comment: Actually, go to the synonym page and look at the list to the very right where it shows the vote count in parens. You should see an "approve" link there (I hope). That's what I just saw on two different synonyms on Mechanics.SE and was able to approve them outright.

Comment: Yep, well spotted :-)

Comment: Really, it should have just created it for you.

Comment: Yeah, I might bug report that on SE.Meta